# Trying to dump images into database but getting error after a few attempts

Tags: python, mysql, opencv

I'm using python to connect to mysql database (on cloud) and then send images to a table. The images are of any face that the camera detects and the face recognition code in python works fine.

Here is the code for uploading images to mysql database

```
                epoch = time.time()
                tt = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",time.localtime(epoch))
                roi = frame[(round(top)-margin-15):(round(bottom)+margin),(round(left)-margin):(round(right)+margin)]
                roi1 = cv2.imencode('.jpg',roi)[1].tostring()


                data_sql = [name,1,roi1,tt]

                if False in temp_matches:
                mycursor.execute(sql_insert_query2,data_sql)

                mydb.commit()
```

**the code above is in a while loop (as long as camera is on)**

The code works if i am sitting still infront of the camera, if i move in and out of the camera view (so that it recognizes again), i get the following error

```
  File "testing_face_recognition_live5.py", line 430, in <module>
    main()
  File "testing_face_recognition_live5.py", line 341, in main
    roi1 = cv2.imencode('.jpg',roi)[1].tostring()
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.5)
 C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\grfmt_base.cpp:145
: error: (-10:Unknown error code -10)
 Raw image encoder error: Empty JPEG image (DNL not supported) in 
function 'cv::BaseImageEncoder::throwOnEror'
```

What should i do to rectify this error ?

Comment: The first step would be to do some debugging -- for example examine the value of the input parameter to `imencode`.

Comment: Your roi can be out of frame range.